# Get User List in Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

i wanna get list of a channel members with this func in Python-Telegram-Bot:

`context.bot.getChatMember("@*****",update.message.chat_id)`

and i do this:

`a=context.bot.getChatMember("@*****",update.message.chat_id)`

but when I wanna print it does not return anything if that user is not in that channel but if that user be in that channel it returns user information

I want to get the value of (a) if that user is not on that channel.

i used pdb and i got 'telegram.error.BadRequest: User not found' this error, but when i want to print it print nothing, and when i wnat print (a) in pdb it says *** NameError: name 'a' is not defined

what I should do?

And how can i get list of members of a channel

Comment: Could you show us your error?

Comment: i used pdb and i got 'telegram.error.BadRequest: User not found' this error, but when i want to print it print nothing, and when i wnat print (a) in pdb it says *** NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Ah, could you add it in in your question, then?

Comment: ow sorry ok im adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, `getChatMember` method is used for checking whether the user is in particular chat (group/channel) or not. So using this method, you cannot retrieve the list of channel members.

As for the reason you're getting the error is ideally **ptb** raises the `BadRequest: User not found` if user is not found in that chat (*isn't it obvious!*). You have to use exceptional blocks to handle these.

Let's say if you're gonna check an user is in chat or not

```
from telegram.error import BadRequest
def is_user_there(channel, chat_id) -> bool:
    try:
       chat_member = context.bot.getChatMember(channel,update.message.chat_id) # this will return a ChatMember object
       if chat_member.status in [‘administrator’, ‘creator’, ‘member’]:
         return True
       else:
         return False
    except BadRequest:
       return False
```

Read more about the [ChatMember](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chatmember.html#telegram.ChatMember) object here